# Is it possible to swap user cookies/profiles with Tamper/Greasemonkey?

Tags: cookies, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

The chrome "swap my cookies" extension allows you to swap between multiple 'profiles' in chrome, that span all sites.

I'm attempting to create something similar for testing my own web services, so I'd like to restrict it to only my domains.

What would be convenient, is to be able to do this from a small userscript using tampermonkey or greasemonkey to add a menu that would swap cookies etc.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get started? Or if it's at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cookies are not httponly you can load them with `document.cookie`, save them with `GM_setValue('cookie_profile_a',document.cookie)` and `GM_getValue('cookie_profile_a')` or in the `localStorage` with `localStorage.setItem('cookie_profile_b',document.cookie)` and `localStorage.getItem('cookie_profile_b')`. For creating a menu in Tampermonkey you can use existing solutions like GM_config (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594346#43462416).

Comment: They arn't httponly... but probably should be to stop stuff like this :P. Would I need to worry about anything else potentially?

Comment: Indeed, if your cookies are not HttpOnly they could be stolen if there is a XSS vulnerability. Other than that I can' think of anything else to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

An extension can have access to all cookies from all domains but content scope script, like page scripts and user-scripts have access to its document cookies only for its domain. That is a security measure to prevent page scripts interfering with cookies from other domains.

Furthermore, page script have no access to browser profiles.

Therefore what you have asked for is not possible with any content/user script.

It is possible for a user-script that runs on multiple domains to read/write cookie data once injected into those domains.
Therefore, a script running on A, B, C domains can get/copy data from cookies from domain A **after getting injected into A**, then store the data and then write the data in cookies in domain B **after getting injected into domain B**.